# Сохранить список установленных пакетов для следующей переустановки системы

Tags: linux, package, fedora, yum

**Fedora, RFRemix**

Давеча довелось переустановить систему. И опять пришлось пару часов танцевать с бубном, чтобы заставить XeLaTeX работать. По ошибкам в консоли зачастую трудно определить какого пакета ему не хватает. Вот, например, выводились сообщения о невозможности загрузить шрифт при работе с кодировкой Т2А, тогда как с Т1 проблем не возникало:

```
....    
! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/12=larm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo ...
```

Но все решилось "методом тыка" установкой пакета **texlive-lh**

Так вот, чтобы не плясать с бубном ещё раз вдруг чего (эта переустановка была внеплановой) хотелось бы сохранить список установленных пакетов **texlive-***

В общем, что проще и быстрее: сохранить список в текстовый файл, создать "пустую" РПМ-ку с зависимостями всех установленных в данный момент пакетов **texlive-*** чтобы она "потащила" всё необходимое, или... Любые другие инструменты и способы.

Comment: да что ж может быть проще текстового файла? `$ rpm -qa | grep ^texlive- > файл`, потом `$ sudo dnf install $(cat файл)`

Comment: Если кто из дебианщиков сюда заглянет, то вот тоже способ: `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @donRumata, рекомендую изучить ключику *grep*, в частности *-w* (на самом деле тут, учитывая дальнейший вызов, либо уж *sed*, либо *awk*). Не говоря о том, что в самом *dpkg* есть много интересных параметров командной строки.

Comment: @0andriy, пробежался глазами по обеим манам - так и не понял где я не прав.

Comment: @donRumata, многословность и лишние вызовы команд. Результат может быть достигнут разными способами.

Comment: @0andriy, ок, какой по-твоему самый лаконичный?